# How to extract a .gz file into current directory? [Python 3.11]

Tags: python, python-3.x, gzip

I need to extract a ".log" file from ".gz" archives, but when I use the code shown below, it creates a file called "name.log" which is still compressed. How do I go about retrieving the uncompressed files?

```py
import shutil
import gzip

file_name = 'name.log.gz'
with gzip.open(file_name,'rb') as f_in:
                  #remove the '.gz'
    with gzip.open(file_name[:-3],'wb') as f_out:
        shutil.copyfileobj(f_in,f_out)
```

Comment: why do you open the output file with gzip? isn't that what causes it to be compressed?

Comment: @njzk2 I'm new to python, so if there's something fundamental I'm not understanding I apologize

Comment: just try to open the output file normally (so `with open(file_name[:-3],'wb') as f_out:`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are decompressing it with the first `gzip.open`, and then recompressing it with the second `gzip.open`! The second one should just be `open`, not `gzip.open`, to write the result without compressing it.